# Failure to Install SQL Server Evaluation

Tags: sql-server, windows-installer

I am attempting to install SQL Server Evaluation for training purposes and use of SSIS. However, after install, and run, it always hangs on 42% as:

[image]

How can I bypass this and complete installation?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you trying to install it on (You should check compatibility with this version)?

Are you connected to the Internet while installing?

Have you fully removed any earlier attempted install(s)?

Have you reviewed [SQL Server logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Also check out [SQL installation stuck at 42%](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a41519a-e9c4-4159-9f16-97cf4c3e6402/sql-installation-stuck-at-42?forum=sqlexpress).

Hopefully some of this will help.